# Mysql ranking from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have two tables, "participations" and "votes".
Every row in the table "votes" contains a "participation_id" to reference the participation for which the vote was cast.

Now, I want to be able to select the *absolute* ranking a participation has based on the number of votes it has.

Normally, this would be simple just using this simple query:

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT(v.id) as votes 
FROM participations as p 
JOIN votes as v on p.id = v.participation_id 
GROUP BY v.participation_id 
ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

BUT, I have to be able to add some WHERE-clauses in there somewhere. So if I do that, I'll just get a *relative* ranking (ie. its ranking relative to the filtered rowset)

Does anybody know if this is possible with just one query!? (ofcourse subqueries are allowed) I hope this question makes sense to anyone.

Comment: Yup, just added the WHERE clauses before GROUP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a variable, which is incremented every row, and select from your query's results, like this:

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT id, votes, rank
from (
  SELECT id, votes, (@rank := @rank + 1) as rank
  from (
    SELECT p.id, COUNT(v.id) as votes 
    FROM participations as p 
    JOIN votes as v on p.id = v.participation_id
    WHERE ... -- add your where clause, if any, here to eliminate completely from results
    GROUP BY v.participation_id 
    ORDER BY votes DESC
  ) x
) y
-- Now join to apply filtering to ranked results, for example:
JOIN participations p1 on p1.id = y.id
where p1.date between '2011-06-01' and now(); -- just making up an example
and p1.gender = 'female'; -- for example
```

Some explanation:

The phrase `(@rank := @rank + 1)` increments the variable *and* returns the result of the increment, which has been given the alias `rank`.

The `x` at the end is the alias of your query's results and is required by the syntax (but any alias will do - I just chose `x`). It is necessary to use the inner query, because that is what provides the ordering - you can't add rank until that's been done.

Note:
Any where clause or other order by processing you want must happen in the *inner* query - the outer query is *only* for the rank processing - it takes the *final* query row set and adds a rank to it.

Comment: I thought that this was the right answer, but it seems to me that this is not the answer I'm looking for. If I add a where-clause to the outer query, the ranking does not seem to be correct. It doesn't return the ABSOLUTE ranking of the participation. Absolute ranking, meaning, how many votes does this participation have compared to ALL participations.

Comment: @ThomasM: I think you should try putting `(@rank := @rank + 1) as rank` in the subselect. Consequently, the outer select should merely pull `rank`, not calculate it. The filtering should probably still be applied to the outer select.

Comment: Yes, that sounds more logcial already, though it's still not the correct resultset, based on tests that I am performing... I'm guessing it's because the ORDER BY happens AFTER the rank calculation.

Comment: This answer is absolutely the right answer, but if you want a `WHERE` clause add it to the *inner* query; it can't go on the outer query - it just wont work there - see updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry but I feel you're still not getting me. I must be expressing my self the wrong way. The rank I receive from this query is just a ranking based on the FILTERED resultset. So what happens is, everything gets filtered through the where clause and AFTER THAT a ranking is given to each row. While what I want is that the ranking happens BEFORE the filtering.

Comment: Ahhh! I think I understand now - you want the overall ranking, *then* filtering - so there could be gaps in the final ranks. See edited answer

Comment: Yes that's it! I already figured out the same solution though, except that you do another join in the end. Why is that? Already marking this as correct though. Thanks!